# @import "Unexpected '@' in program"

Tags: ios, ios7, xcode5

I updated project to Xcode 5 and enabled modules in build settings.
However, I see compiler error `Unexpected '@' in program` when I use `@import`.

```
#ifndef __IPHONE_7_0
#warning "This project uses features only available in iOS SDK 7.0 and later."
#endif

#ifdef __cplusplus
#import <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#endif

#ifdef __OBJC__
@import SystemConfiguration;
@import UIKit;
```

Is it anything else that should be done?

Comment: add the code where you use @import

Answer (score 64, accepted):

From the comment of `@hw731` I think you use badly `@import` :

old syntax to import framework :

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
```

but now, you can use the new syntax :

```
@import UIKit;
```

you need to enable theses modules to use the keyword `@import` (it's enable by default when you create a new project with Xcode 5) :

[image]

Have a look [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/49850/whats-new-in-objective-c-and-foundation-in-ios-7).

Comment: No, I use correct @import UIKit; These settings are also set.

Comment: The problem was that I use workspace, and the second project occasionally lost its module settings.

Comment: This worked for me. I have a project that was started back in iPhone OS 2.0 and this was set to NO. Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

Got same error, checked the standard places:

- Yes, I have correct code syntax
- Yes, all the "Apple LLVM 5.0 - Languages - Modules" settings are YES. Both in this project and each its targets.
- Yes, I'm using a workspace, but checked that all projects have enabled Modules. Both projects and their each targets.
- Yes, checked I don't have any funny "smart" quotes anywhere
- Yes, checked that I'm in a header.h or file.m file (not .mm/.c/.cpp/.hpp)

The problem was that the header file was **imported into file.mm** file, which doesn't seem to support the new @import module syntax! Converted that header back to old style #import format and everything was fine again.

Comment: I too have some .mm files for C++ (Protocol Buffers). I converted back to the old syntax with #import in the .pch file. Everything compiles fine now.

Answer (score 5):

I also found that using following code in pch file:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
#import <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#endif
```

are not compatible with `@import`.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem when i subclass UIActivity and write property in .m file as

```
@property(nonatomic, strong)NSArray *activityItems;
```

fixed by moving this property to .h file.