# Obj-C Modules don't work in workspace

Tags: objective-c, ios7, xcode5

I have some classes that use the new `@import` module directive and it works fine in my non-workspace project but once I move those files over to a project in a workspace I get the error `Unexpected '@' in program` similar to this question: [@import "Unexpected '@' in program"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19272683/import-unexpected-in-program)
However I DO have `Enable Modules` build settings ticked to Yes. The static library in my workspace project also has this option enabled. I tired cleaning the build as well with no luck. Are there any other settings I'm missing?

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you have ticked the enable modules in both your project and target of your static library and main project.

Comment: I was missing it on my project however I enabled it, cleaned and I still have the same issue.

Comment: And you're sure it's enabled on all of your targets? Also, have you tried quitting XCode and re-opening it? Sometimes that will fix odd bugs.

Comment: Still no dice. I might try to put example project on github showing the issue.

Comment: Have you made an example project that I could take a look at?

Answer (score 3):

Are you using Objective-C++? @import does not work in .mm files.