# @property Unexpected '@' in program

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I make this program for 1 year and now, when I try to add new object I got this: Unexpected '@' in program.

Simple code = an ocean of problems.
I have tried to recreate file for many times, I have tried to close and reopen Xcode. Nothing.
I have changed 'NO' to 'YES' like people say [@import "Unexpected '@' in program"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19272683/import-unexpected-in-program). Nothing.

I am desperate.
Sorry for my English. Thanks :)

MNClient.h same problem

I see no problem with code.

[image: Strange Errors]
[image: Strange Errors]

Nothing important here.

```
//
//  MNClient.m
//  CM
//
//  Created by Michael Nitsenko on 7/29/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 PrivatBank. All rights reserved.
//

#import "MNClient.h"

@implementation MNClient

@end

//
//  MNEventObject.m
//  CM
//
//  Created by Michael on 11/6/13.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 PrivatBank. All rights reserved.
//

#import "MNEventObject.h"

@implementation MNEventObject

@end
```

ARC don't explain error in MNClient.h and I thought about it.

There is CM-Prefix.pch

```
//
// Prefix header for all source files of the 'ContactManager' target in the 'ContactManager' project
//

#import <Availability.h>

#ifndef __IPHONE_4_0
#warning "This project uses features only available in iOS SDK 4.0 and later."
#endif

#ifdef __OBJC__
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "GAI.h"
#import "GAIFields.h"

#import "CMDefines.h"
#endif
```

Looks better :)

[image: Nice]

Comment: Show the contents of `MNClient.h`.

Comment: Are you **only** including this in a .m file?  It acts as if the file is not Objective-C.

Comment: Or you may have edited the file with the wrong editor and gotten some non-UTF8 character codes in there.

Comment: I use only Xcode editor. And I remake file (with Xcode) for many times.

Comment: And what file are you including this in?  You could have mucked up a prior include file, leaving an open `{` or some such.  Or simply have the #import in the wrong place.

Comment: OK now show the implementation file (just the lines preceding the inclusion of the first header file).

Comment: (Show us the first few lines of the .m you're including this file in.)

Comment: No, your edit tells us nothing new.  We want to see the implementation (`.m`) file.

Comment: show us your prefix.pch file(s) as well

Comment: Let's see the .m file!!!

Comment: (And don't post images of files.  Use copy/paste from your editor, then highlight the pasted source and press the `{}` button at the top of the edit window to indent the source by 4 characters.)

Comment: I cannot see anything wrong.  Something to try; replace `#import "MNClient.h"` in `MNClientEvent.h` with `@class MNClient;` and see if that helps, but I doubt it will.  Something looks very wrong with your project/system.

Comment: You should be able to drop all the `#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>` lines as well, given then are in your prefix file.  You will need `#import "MNClient.h"` in your `MNEventObject.m` file as you've removed it from the header.

Comment: Check target dependencies for MNClient.m file.