# Xcode 5.1.1 AppDelegate.h and main.m error

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode5

I created a project a few week ago and opened it today. When i left the project there were no errors and everything worked fine, but now i have three errors and don't know why.

Here my AppDelegate.h :

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

@end
```

And here my main.m:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import "AppDelegate.h"

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

Here the errors:

```
/main.m: Semantic Issue Use of undeclared identifier 'AppDelegate'
AppDelegate.h: Parse Issue Expected identifier or '('
AppDelegate.h:  Parse Issue '@end' must appear in an Objective-C context
```

Comment: Can you describe the errors here in addition to providing the linked image? If your link ever gets broken, we want this question to still be useful for future viewers.

Comment: I saw an similar issue yesterday which did not make sense at all.  What version of OSX are you running? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25014772/property-unexpected-in-program#comment38898081_25014772

Comment: Look carefully project's `.pch` file. Is it correct, are there all `#define` constructions right? And how about `#include` or `#import` directives?

Comment: i use osx Mavericks 10.9.4

Comment: my .pch file: #import <Availability.h>

#ifndef __IPHONE_5_0
#warning "This project uses features only available in iOS SDK 5.0 and later."
#endif

#ifdef __OBJC__
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#endif

Comment: AFAIK, there's a "licence" kind of in the beginning of both files. Try looking for "out of comment" characters there.

Comment: thanks it works i forgo a * at the top.