# can't import embedded framework with xcode 6 GM

Tags: ios, frameworks, xcode6

I added a framework target in my project. But when I attempt to import the framework, the compiler will return an error `Use of '@import' when modules are disabled`. I have already included the arm64 architecture in its Architectures build settings. And I can see the framework in **Build Phases**. I can import a framework in a new project instead of my current project. Is there any additional config I missed?

Answer (score 102, accepted):

> Use of '@import' when modules are disabled

Error msg says you are trying to use `modules` by `@import` when it is disabled. Goto build settings and enable `modules` or use `#import` instead.

[image]

Enable it by changing to YES

Comment: All the frameworks will not support modules i guess, so you might have to use #import instead

Comment: what you gotta dig through all the LLVM <X.n> options and set this setting? i would expect nothing less from what I've seen so far with xcode/swift.

Comment: @import GoogleMobileAds;
But I get error saying Module 'GoogleMobileAds' not found. I also installed latest GoogleMobileAds 7.0 from pods

Comment: @KumarMaishi I also still have this error. How did you fix it?

Comment: @KarenAnne I fixed this by removing GoogleMobileAds from pods and added by just drag and drop

Comment: @MaishiWadhuwani dragging what and where you drop it, i'm confused, can you help me with that, because i'm stuck on this error

Comment: @PradnyanandMilindPohare Add GoogleMobileAds drag and drop directly in your project. And add in "Linked Framework and Libararies"

Answer (score 39):

For those that still have problems with enabling Modules.

> The problem could be that the header file was imported into file.mm
>   file (objective-c++), which is not supported to the @import module
>   syntax.

Here is a good answer explaining other possible problems.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/21921045/2269679

Comment: This is correct! You saved me hours of mucking about!

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem in Xcode 7. I have found the solution. It's to wrap Google Analytics into Cocoa Class (`.m` and `.h`), and use this wrapper from your `.mm` files. Also you should enable modules in Xcode.

For more information, please check my answer (and my Gist) here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36267420/882187

I'm sorry, if it looks like I'm trying to spam, but I don't know how to re-link all those questions and answers better in one self-containing discussion thread.