# How to import GoogleMobileAds framework?

Tags: ios, admob

I am following the instructions on the following page to integrate admob with my iOS application:

https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/ios/quick-start#manually_using_the_sdk_download

Unfortunately, when I try:

```
@import GoogleMobileAds;
```

my project won't compile, with the error:

> Use of '@import' when modules are disabled

I tried the following:

1. Using `#import` instead of `@import`. This does not work, because "GoogleMobileAds" does not show up. Instead I have to import the framework, which leads to many errors showing up, which xcode doesn't even display because there are too many.
2. Going to my target -> build settings -> Apple LLVM 6.0 - Language - Modules -> Enable Modules (C and Objective-C) and setting it to "YES". Even after doing this the same error appears.

How does one fix this ?

Comment: very detailed answer for this issue. 
please refer this question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25883153/cant-import-embedded-framework-with-xcode-6-gm

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It seems that one needs to use #import , and specify each specific file as necessary. For example:

```
#import <GoogleMobileAds/GoogleMobileAds.h>
```

I guess the instructions on the Google site are out of date.

Comment: I was hoping for this solution to work as it has for other frameworks but I still get a file not found error.