# How to use PHPhotoLibrary in a mixed code Objective-C/C++ file (a .mm file)?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, include, phphotolibrary

I am trying to use the PHPhotoLibrary class in an iOS project, but need it in one of my mixed code Objective-C/C++ files.  I am getting a build error bc apparently the needed import is not correct. The Apple docs [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Photos/Reference/PHPhotoLibrary_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/PHPhotoLibrary:) clearly show that @import Photos is to be used, so in my Build Settings I turned on "Enable Modules (C and Objective-C)" and added @import Photos with my other imports.  That however did not fix Xcode's objection to my using @import Photos. The problem is as one of the posts for this SO question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25883153/cant-import-embedded-framework-with-xcode-6-gm) explains, you can only use the @import Photos style of include in .mm files.

(I'm not using Swift, only Objective-C and in a few files mixed Objective-C and C++)

How then can I properly import/include in my .mm file so my PHPhotoLibrary code will build?

Comment: Are you using swift or objective-c for your current project?

Comment: @Peter -- I'm using Objective-C

Comment: I have answered on your Question. please check and let me know of your thoughts.

Comment: That fixed it. Duh. Wish docs were more clear. Thx.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to import Photos.framwork

```
  #import <Photos/Photos.h>
```

in your .mm file

Comment: Indeed it is.  Sorry for the delayed response.