# In Xcode, with the use of @import, is there still a need to link framework?

Tags: ios, llvm, xcode5

With the introduction of module (via @import), is there still a need to link Apple's own framework using the old way, or is that only useful for external framework only?

Should we remove all native SDK frameworks from the Frameworks folder to clean things up?

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18947634/251513).

Comment: Thanks, I am familiar with the concept of module.  I want to know if linking of framework is still useful with the advent of it.

Answer (score 0):

all #import and #include directives are mapped to use @import automatically for Apple framework - @import is the way to go! In regards to the clean up, You can remove them. There was a bug in some cocoapods though where it didn't recognise the framework unless it was #import though, but I think this bug has been fixed now.