# QuartzCore framework bundled with UIKit framework in Xcode 5 and above?

Tags: ios, xcode

Is the QuartzCore framework bundled with UIKit framework in Xcode 5?

Earlier I had to manually add the framework and then do layer operations. That seems to have changed in the new version of Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a new project, then it's probably using Objective-C code modules and linking the QuartzCore framework automatically. 
Modules are enabled by default for projects created in Xcode5

Check to see if it's enabled in your build settings: 
[image]

Clang documentation: http://clang.llvm.org/docs/Modules.html

See this related answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18947634/1144632