# Why doesn't @import (module) work in Cocos2d ios?

Tags: ios, xcode, import, cocos2d-iphone

Sorry, this is probably a very basic question, but I can't find an answer for it.  I am trying to add two modules to a Cocos2d project (@import CoreBluetooth; and @import QuartzCore;).  When try to add them to my header file I get an error that says, "Unexpected '@' in program."  Are modules not supported in Cocos2d? Do I need to do something to enable them? Am I overlooking something else?  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modules are by default enabled in new Xcode projects. For existing projects,
go to the "Build Settings"  and set "Enable Modules" to YES:

[image]

If you set "Link Frameworks Automatically" to YES as well then all imported
frameworks are automatically added to the link libraries.

A good overview of the `@import` compiler feature is

- [@import vs #import - iOS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18947516/import-vs-import-ios-7)

Comment: Thanks for the reply Martin. I just created this project in 5.1.1. When I go to "Build Settings" I don't even see this option (I think because it is on by default). The link you posted is one of the questions I read before submitting the question but it didn't solve my problem.

Comment: @RyanTensmeyer: Make sure that "All" settings are selected, not just "Basic". See screenshot.

Comment: That did the trick. I'm glad (and a little embarrassed) that it was that simple.

Comment: To clarify, switching the filter from "Basic" to "All" was the solution.