# Using @import in a CocoaPods project

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, clang, cocoapods

I have a header in a CocoaPods project I'm working on in Xcode 6, in which I have an `@import Cocoa;` statement. It builds fine in its own project, but when I integrate it into the client app, I get the following error:

> Use of '@import' when modules are disabled

I checked the **CLANG_ENABLE_MODULES** setting in every target of my client project, as well as every target in the Pods project, and every single one is set to `YES`. What could be triggering this error. I can switch back to a `#import`, which does fix it, but I'd like to understand why this is happening, since everything looks like it's configured properly.

I pushed my podspec (UnzipKit), but I also replaced the `@import` statements with `#import` to get it working. Also, I'm using Cocoapods 0.35.0. If you use this in your Podfile, it'll get you the `@import` version.

```
pod 'UnzipKit', :git => 'https://github.com/abbeycode/UnzipKit.git', :commit => '38cd0225015a245b0d3167666b3f40d57f99147a'
```

Comment: Do you resolve problem? I also use cocoapods with library that use `@import`. In one project all works fine, in other I get the same error. Modules are enabled everywhere.

Comment: @Sk0prion No I didn't. As mentioned, I had to revert back to `#import`s everywhere.

Answer (score 6):

```
Use of '@import' when modules are disabled
```

If you are using Xcode version6 then make sure that below two things should be enable inside Language Module settings. Refer the attached screenshot:-
[image]

If you are using Xcode version lower than 6, You will get error because the module only work with apple framework and you cannot use them in other framework or third party Apps. You can check [here](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/)

For more details of this answer check this [stackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18947516/import-vs-import-ios-7)

Comment: Why would someone downvote this? That's the right answer, you can only use `@import` on Apple frameworks like `@MapKit`.

Comment: I updated the question to mention that I _am_ using Xcode 6. Besides, I am importing Cocoa and Foundation, which are Apple frameworks.

Comment: This doesn't solve my problem. I can add "@import" but then sometimes I get the same error.