# Error while registering with GCM for iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-cloud-messaging, cocoapods

I am using [Google instructions link](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/ios/client?configured=true) to integrate GCM with iOS app .

I integrated Cocoapod file in my project as per the instructions.Now after installation I am getting bellow error in GGLConfiguration.h and GGLInstanceID.h as in below screenshot:

Getting this issue when adding this below snippet in appdelegate.m

```
  #import "AppDelegate.h" 

 //***** this code *****//
  @interface AppDelegate ()
  @property(nonatomic, strong) void (^registrationHandler)
       (NSString *registrationToken, NSError *error);
  @property(nonatomic, assign) BOOL connectedToGCM;
  @property(nonatomic, strong) NSString* registrationToken;
  @property(nonatomic, assign) BOOL subscribedToTopic;
  @end


 and in appdelegate.h

 #import <Google/CloudMessaging.h>
  //***************/
```

[image]

If anyone has faced similar problem please help me ..

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved My issue by replacing:

```
   @import UIKit

   @import Foundation

   // to

   #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

   #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
```

for more info: [Please refer this](https://github.com/jessesquires/JSQMessagesViewController/issues/541)

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you need to enable modules for your Objective-C project.

In your build settings, it looks like this:

[image]

And more information can be seen [in this very related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18947516/import-vs-import-ios-7).

p.s.

I'm not sure what modules being disabled has to do with a "1003" error, b.t.w. What part of your code does that error come from? Do you have multiple questions you're combining together?

Comment: thank you for your response .. Actually,I am trying to fix my issue using "pod try Google" sample app which pops up 1003 ..As You have mentioned, my app settings is set to "Enable modules == YES"

Comment: so is everything working okay now?  or do you need to enter in a separate question about the 1003 error (which you edited away from this question)?

Comment: Still the same @import issue ..hope  this can be due to missing "GoogleServices-Info.plist" in my project

Comment: Please see my updated question once to help in resolving my issue

Comment: Check your other targets (e.g. the Cocoapods ones) and see if "Enable Modules" is set to "`NO`" accidentally.