# Swift: Cannot find protocol declaration

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, swift2

I've got a really strange bug with Swift 2. I am using `EventKitUI` and I am able to display the view controller. When I try to add support for the delegate though I get two build errors:

> Cannot find protocol declaration for 'EKEventEditViewDelegate'
>
> Expected a type

The errors are showing in my projects `-swift.h` (the project mixes Swift and Objective-c).

Any idea why this is happening? Unless I'm missing something I can't see any basic mistakes (typo etc.) that could cause this.

Comment: Hi, could you show how you import EventKit ?

Comment: ```import EventKitUI ``` at the top of the file. I also added the framework via the project settings.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Strange fix but by importing `#import <EventKitUI/EventKitUI.h>` in my bridging header the issue was resolved.

Comment: Check the difference between @import and #import. May explain this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18947516/import-vs-import-ios-7

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, this happens if your protocol includes things that aren't supported in ObjC, such as swift structs. Whenever I get this, I usually find that a structs is a part of something that I was expecting to send back and forth from the protocol

Comment: This explains my issues since my imports are correct. There are two functions inside of the delegate that were returning a swift Struct. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

All of a sudden I got this error when using CocoaPods. I fixed it by importing SDWebImage in my Swift bridging header like this:

```
#import <SDWebImage/SDWebImage-umbrella.h>
```