# Extending a Public class for partial public access in Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cocoa

I am working on a Swift framework which has majority of Swift files and very few Objective C files. Since I don't want my Objective-C files to be available outside the SDK and not even under headers folder, I gave them project access and now use them internally with a module map.

Here is how my modulemap file looks like:

```
module MySDKPrivate {

    header "CardDetails.h"
    export *
}
```

Now, in order to access this CardDetails file, I just need to import `MySDKPrivate` module in the required Swift class. All good till here.

Now, let's say I have a `public` class, named `Payment.swift`. This class is responsible for executing SDK operations partially hidden to the user, hence it is under the `project` access, so it does not show up in the headers when SDK is distributed.

There are some methods such as `authenticate` and `getSessionExpireDate` which are accessed by a `PaymentDoor.swift` class, which is basically nothing but an extension to `Payment` class for partial read & write injection, helping to get the minor info in/out of `Payment` class. Here is the sample signature of `PaymentDoor.swift`

```
//Extension to inject data in and out of the Internal Payment.swift
public extension Payment{

}
```

And here is the `Payment.Swift` class

```
import MySDKPrivate

public class Payment {
    let username: String
    let password: String
    let cardDetails: CardDetails

    public init(userName: String, password: String, cardNumber: String) {
        self.username = userName
        self.password = password

        let cardDetails = CardDetails()
        cardDetails.cardNumber = cardNumber

        self.cardDetails = cardDetails
    }

    public func authenticate() -> Bool{
        //Some logic
        return true
    }

    private func generateAuthkey(){
        //Should not be accessible with the extension
    }
}
```

This is another reason why I want to keep this `Payment` class as `public` and inside `project` access for headers, because If I make it available as public under headers, SDK user would see the name of my modulemap and all the code in Payment class and could use the objective-c files as well with importing the module map. Although now also the name of the module map comes up by Auto Help but at least it's not visible directly.

I still think there could be a better way to inject data in and out of a public class which hides my module name OR Hiding Objective-C files could be done in a better way may be. If yes, please help !

Comment: How about declaring as `internal` the parts of the class you don't want exposed outside the sdk?