# Azure pipeline fails during xcode build for iOS project

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Trying to build iOS project with xcode build. Using -

1. Xcode 12.4
2. Agent Specification - macOS-10.15
3. Workspace or project path - Project.xcworkspace
4. Configuration - Release (Tried with Debug also, it gives more error)
5. Scheme -valid name
6. SDK - iphoneos

Now After xcode build using Azure pipeline give following error.

We can build this xcode on locally and Gitlab too. But same code is failing on Azure Devops.
Kindly help.

```
2021-05-12T13:00:30.6465950Z ❌  /Users/runner/work/1/s/Project/Framework/csdk_common.framework/Modules/module.modulemap:2:19: umbrella header 'csdk_common.h' not found
2021-05-12T13:00:30.6466920Z 
2021-05-12T13:00:30.6468430Z   umbrella header "csdk_common.h"
2021-05-12T13:00:30.6471390Z                   ^
2021-05-12T13:00:30.6471830Z 
2021-05-12T13:00:30.6472160Z 
2021-05-12T13:00:30.6472470Z 
2021-05-12T13:00:30.6473810Z ❌  /Users/runner/work/1/s/Project/TTS/main_internal.swift:2:8: could not build Objective-C module 'csdk_common'
2021-05-12T13:00:30.6474420Z 
2021-05-12T13:00:30.6475000Z import csdk_common
2021-05-12T13:00:30.6475580Z        ^
2021-05-12T13:00:30.6475930Z 
2021-05-12T13:00:30.6476250Z 
2021-05-12T13:00:30.6730310Z ** BUILD FAILED **
2021-05-12T13:00:30.6731680Z 
2021-05-12T13:00:30.6732100Z 
2021-05-12T13:00:30.6732840Z The following build commands failed:
2021-05-12T13:00:30.6733510Z    CompileSwift normal arm64
2021-05-12T13:00:30.6740330Z    CompileSwiftSources normal arm64 com.apple.xcode.tools.swift.compiler
2021-05-12T13:00:30.6746120Z (2 failures)
2021-05-12T13:00:30.7025590Z ##[error]Error: /usr/bin/xcodebuild failed with return code: 65
2021-05-12T13:00:30.7365340Z ##[section]Finishing: Xcode build
```

Comment: Did you get an answer for this, I am still facing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Please check the repos branch, and make sure you have added this under framework header file. Maybe you did not push the right project and necessary part into the azure devops repos.

```
#import "xxx\csdk_common.h"
```

More info you could check [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32923483/umbrella-header-for-module-myframework-does-not-include-header-otherframework) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30355133/swift-framework-umbrella-header-h-not-found).