# Cocoapods use_frameworks! import issue

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoapods, facebook-ios-sdk

I want to use some Swift pods in my Objective-C app, so I need to use frameworks instead of static libraries. But enabling `use_frameworks!` in my Podfile causes tones of `#import` errors.

My Podfile:

```
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

pod 'AFNetworking', '2.6.0'
pod 'Typhoon'
pod 'SSKeychain'
pod 'JBWebViewController'
pod 'TTTAttributedLabel'
pod 'HockeySDK'
pod 'GoogleAnalytics'
pod 'Intercom'
pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'
pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'
pod 'UIButton+Activity'
pod 'HexColors'
pod 'AFNetworkActivityLogger'
pod 'HCSStarRatingView', :git => 'https://github.com/hsousa/HCSStarRatingView.git'
pod 'LGSideMenuController'
pod 'DateTools'
pod 'SDWebImage'
pod 'SSCWhatsAppActivity'
pod 'UIViewController+BlockSegue'
```

The first problem was with `SSKeychain` pod:

[image: SSKeychain Error]

In code I'm including SSKeychain using "quotes" `#import "SSKeychain/SSKeychain.h"`, but if I understand right, I need to use `<angle>` from now `#import <SSKeychain/SSKeychain.h>`? But in this case I receive same error, but in my code.

My Build Phases:

[image: Build Phases]

Anyway I have found fork of SSKeychain with "quotes" import (https://github.com/adamwulf/sskeychain/commit/2b7fd878415e8e4f23f74636cdd8c993466d0749) and switched to those version.

But now I have same issue with many other pods (almost with all of them):

[image: FBSDKCoreKit error]

Import in app: `#import "FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h"`

Do I really need to fork each repo and change import statements?? Or I'm including pods in wrong way?

PS: I'm cleaning derived data and project before each build attempt.

Cocoapods Version: 0.39.0

Comment: Which version of CocoaPods are you using? Last one? 0.39.0?

Comment: exit project, go out and run "pod install"

Comment: @DiegoFreniche I have tried both 0.39.0 and version built from latest master branch.

Comment: If you didn't install all pods at the same session, I suggest you to first remove all pod libraries and then add all of them again. It works in my case.

Comment: @HarshIT I've tried to remove `/Pods`, `Podfile.lock` and `workspace`, and run clean `pod install` - same problem.

Answer (score 12):

As you've used [Modules](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18947634/225503) in your Podfile, why don't you just:

```
@import SSKeychain;
```

instead of:

```
#import <SSKeychain/SSKeychain.h>
```

To test that:

- create a simple iOS project, just with one ViewController
- create a Podfile using your code above
- run pod install
- open the Workspace
- build & run: it compiles OK

Comment: When I'm trying use `@import` instead of `#import` I receive error that framework not found: https://s.mail.ru/GNxY2NAxse12/img-2015-12-23-12-42-25.png. I think this is a main problem

Comment: I've tested in an empty project and it works, please create a test project to ensure this works, then compare your target with the new project's target

Comment: I have finally figured out it! The problem was fixed by removing `Pods.framework` from **Link Binary With Libraries** and adding them again manually. Thank you for your help! You can edit your answer and I will  accept it :)

Comment: Better: auto-answer yourself. You've found what works!

Comment: Thanks Diego. I found that after adding `use_frameworks!` the classic `#import`s were giving me problems (duplicate definitions and such). By replacing them with `@import`s my build is fixed again.

Answer (score 7):

I have finally figured out it! The problem was fixed by removing `Pods.framework` from **Link Binary With Libraries** and adding them again manually.

Thanks for help!

Comment: That's weird, did you actually open the workspace rather than the project ?

Comment: @AncAinu yes, also I have 2 targets in project and frameworks were linked only against one of them, so I had to add **Embed Pods Frameworks** build step manually :(

Comment: Next time, it would be useful to run this (https://github.com/CocoaPods/cocoapods-deintegrate) to remove all traces of CocoaPods, then `pod install` again

Comment: @Ponf Happened to me too, had 3 targets but did link the `Pods.framework` to the first of them only in **Build Settings > Embed Pods Frameworks**. Sad it doesn't do that automatically.

Comment: Where is this "Link Binary With Libraries"  
I don't see it?

Answer (score 1):

Also check error messages on `pod install`.

In my case I was using a custom import in `FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS`, and just because I was doing that, whenever I did `pod install` the extra search paths that CocoaPods adds were not being added. So I had to remove my custom path and then they showed up. Then I added my custom path.

Might be a good idea to do `pod deintegrate`, delete de xcworkspace file and do `pod install` once more. Then add your custom build settings.

This is the error I was getting:

```
[!] The App [Debug] target overrides the FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS
build setting defined in Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-AppLib/Pods-AppLib.debug.xcconfig. 
This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, what was an issue I already downloaded few ObjC Pods for my Objective C Project then I need one swift pod so I enable `use_framwork` in my pod file and install that swift pod, After installing that swift pod import issue arrives for ObjeC Libraries in many classes, So

**What I did to fix this issue?**

1. Cut all Objective C pods from pod file
2. Open terminal and run command: `cd path/myProject`
3. Terminal run command: `pod install`
4. Past it (all Objective C pods) again in pod file and save it
5. Terminal run command: `pod install`