# Cocoapods use_frameworks! caused strange compiler errors in the old OC codes

Tags: xcode, cocoapods

I added `use_frameworks!` in my pod file, running `pod install` again (without any other changes). Then I got the compiler error like `'Masonry.h' file not found with <angled> include; use "quotes" instead.`

Although I believed those pod header files should be used with `<...>` I did change them to `"..."`. But then I got the error like `Redefinition of 'FMTokenizerCursor'` (from FMDB pod)

I felt like this maybe a cocoapod bug (I am using 1.0.1) so I upgraded it to `cocoapods-1.1.0.beta.2`, same error.  `pod deintegrate & pod install` made no difference.

I found these is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34429793/cocoapods-use-frameworks-import-issue). But the answers there did not work for me.

I tried both Xcode 7 & 8, clean ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData

same error too.

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem as you, I try to search for Search Paths in the Build Settings of the project, then add to the User header search paths $ (SRCROOT) and select recursive. But that does not work ... Then I put the "use_frameworks!" was removed from the podfile, recompile the project, problem solved =-=

Answer (score -1):

Here's an example for a Podfile using the new format. (This example project has 2 targets), Try it.
also, make sure you don't edit this file in textEdit. (xCode is preferred)

```
abstract_target 'YourProject-abstract' do
    use_frameworks!

    pod 'Alamofire', '3.5.0'
    pod 'ObjectMapper'
    pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'
    pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'
    pod 'AlamofireImage'
    target 'MyProject' do
    end
    target 'MyProject-staging' do
    end
end
```

Comment: I knew "abstract_target" introduced in 1.0 but I don't think that will fix my compiler error.

Comment: It's just an example, if you have 1 target, dont use it. i actually think your problem is the "quote" error you got. try editing your file in xcode, and use a single quotation (')