# React-Native video is not playing audio

Tags: react-native

I am trying to use react-native-video in my app but when video plays, audio is not playing. Only video without audio is playing. (In Android, both video, audio is playing well. Only in iOS, audio is not playing)

I found a solution on github and tried it, but got a new error. How to fix this new error?
[Here](https://github.com/react-native-video/react-native-video/issues/874) is the link.

[image]

[image]

This is new error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to solve that compilation error, you'll need to add this to the top of the file you added the `AVAudioSession` code to:

```
@import AVFoundation;
```

**OR** (this is the one they show in the example):

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
```

(The first one doesn't require that you add the framework -- see [@import vs #import - iOS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18947516/import-vs-import-ios-7))

Also, just wanted to make sure you had also tried this fix listed on the answer page you linked to:

```
<Video
    ...
    ignoreSilentSwitch="ignore"
/>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Should I add both "AVFoundation" and "<AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>"?  And also should I add these to the top of the AppDelegate.m file?  ( I added ignoreSilentSwitch prop also, but not working.)

Comment: Not both. Just one. Yes, that's the top of the AppDelegate.m file

Comment: Thank you. Solved.