# Objective c / Module 'SVProgressHUD' not found

Tags: objective-c, cocoapods

[image]

During the test on the machine, I checked the error message.
This problem occurs even though it is installed normally through **cocoapods**, how can I solve it?

Comment: Choose Product > Build with Xcode.

Comment: I built the product, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to enable the module feature. See if the 'Enable Modules' flag is set to Yes in your project settings. For more information see the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18947634/211292

Comment: Followed these instructions but could not be resolved... I guess it's a pod problem.