# Thread 1: signal SIGABRT

Tags: sdk, swift3, adobe, ios-simulator

I get the above error when I run the simulation for my Xcode project
This appears in the O__abort_with_payload file

```
dyld`__abort_with_payload:
    0x10aae66f8 <+0>:  movl   $0x2000209, %eax          ; imm = 0x2000209 
    0x10aae66fd <+5>:  movq   %rcx, %r10
    0x10aae6700 <+8>:  syscall 
->  0x10aae6702 <+10>: jae    0x10aae670c               ; <+20>
    0x10aae6704 <+12>: movq   %rax, %rdi
    0x10aae6707 <+15>: jmp    0x10aae6014               ; cerror_nocancel
    0x10aae670c <+20>: retq   
    0x10aae670d <+21>: nop    
    0x10aae670e <+22>: nop    
    0x10aae670f <+23>: nop
```

the error appears on the line "->  0x10aae6702 <+10>: jae    0x10aae670c               ; <+20>"

There's also a message on the console

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/AdobeCreativeSDKCore.framework/AdobeCreativeSDKCore
  Referenced from: /Users/kelvinnjeri/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/0B163356-1560-479A-9CC0-2EC04084C5E3/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/FA936BDF-9607-4810-AEA5-F97A2EEFCA14/CloudiTv11.app/CloudiTv11
  Reason: image not found
(lldb)
```

[image: error message]

I have the 'AdobeCreativeSDKCore' and 'AdobeCreativeSDKimages' installed as a framework, the project built but the error came up

[image: podfile]

On a separate occasion, I also tried to manually include the Frameworks in my main project files and use a bridging header file to bridge it.

[image: SDK in project files]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [dyld: Library not loaded with cocoapods 0.37 and Xcode 6.3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30053144/dyld-library-not-loaded-with-cocoapods-0-37-and-xcode-6-3)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It’s because you are using a custom framework so you need to put it inside the Embedded Binaries in the section General. Select the frameworks NOT the bundle, Unselect Copy items if it was and select Create groups.

[Steps screenshoted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Wnol.png)

Enjoy !

Answer (score 1):

***make sure**

`install builds only is unchecked and based on dependency analysis is checked in both embeded frameworks and copy pod resources`

[image]

[image]

Answer (score -1):

For me unlink react-native-crop-image-picker and react-native-input-test-mask solved the issue.