# Framework Pod says Library not loaded

Tags: swift, xcode, debugging

Hi I'm making an application for ios that uses a pod library called Signature.Framework (Substantially allows you to make the signature). When I start the application on the XCode simulator everything works perfectly when I go to test the application on the physical device, I get the error below. What is more due and how can I solve it?

**Error:**

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/Signature.framework/Signature
  Referenced from: /var/containers/Bundle/Application/DD816747-0B6F-46FB-93E6-6C28DCFFED7F/myapp.app/myapp
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/DD816747-0B6F-46FB-93E6-6C28DCFFED7F/myapp.app/Frameworks/Signature.framework/Signature: code signing blocked mmap() of '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/DD816747-0B6F-46FB-93E6-6C28DCFFED7F/myapp.app/Frameworks/Signature.framework/Signature'
    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/DD816747-0B6F-46FB-93E6-6C28DCFFED7F/myapp.app/Frameworks/Signature.framework/Signature: code signing blocked mmap() of '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/DD816747-0B6F-46FB-93E6-6C28DCFFED7F/myapp.app/Frameworks/Signature.framework/Signature'
    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/DD816747-0B6F-46FB-93E6-6C28DCFFED7F/myapp.app/Frameworks/Signature.framework/Signature: stat() failed with errno=1
    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/DD816747-0B6F-46FB-93E6-6C28DCFFED7F/myapp.app/Frameworks/Signature.framework/Signature: code signing blocked mmap() of '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/DD816747-0B6F-46FB-93E6-6C28DCFFED7F/myapp.app/Frameworks/Signature.framework/Signature'
    /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/DD816747-0B6F-46FB-93E6-6C28DCFFED7F/myapp.app/Frameworks/Signature.framework/Signature: stat() failed with errno=1
(lldb)
```

**Linking:**

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24333981/ios-app-with-framework-crashed-on-device-dyld-library-not-loaded-xcode-6-beta check this link

Comment: @chiragshah I already tried with the answers in this question but it does not work

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30053144/dyld-library-not-loaded-with-cocoapods-0-37-and-xcode-6-3/30166310#30166310 try this out

Comment: @chiragshah I also tried these solutions, but nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution 1

In my case i set the Pods.framework to optional and it fixed the issue , It wasn't being copied to device by the .sh script and so the app crashed:

[image: Picture]

### Solution 2

remove your project from DerivedData

`User/YourPcName/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjectNameFolder`

Comment: From me, even with your solution, I always have the same error

Comment: the strange thing is that it only happens on the physical device, I do not have problems on the emulator

Comment: @riki run pod deintegrate then pod install

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176691/discussion-between-riki-and-mohamad-reza-koohkan).