# Link SceneKit Framework avoid crash on iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, linker, scenekit

I have an app that supports iOS 7 and greater.  For one of the views I want to use SceneKit, if the app is running on iOS 8 or greater.  I do this by using this bit of code

```
if(SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"8.0")){
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"3DIdentifier" sender:cell];
    }
    else{
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"2DIdentifier" sender:cell];
    }
}
```

The trouble is that when using the iOS 7 simulator the app won't run.

Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /System/Library/Frameworks/SceneKit.framework/SceneKit: mach-o, but not built for iOS simulator

Is there a way to link SceneKit that enables the app to still build and run on iOS 7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

are you weak-linking SceneKit?
See https://stackoverflow.com/a/16936512 and https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFrameworks/Concepts/WeakLinking.html

Comment: Success!  I was not weak linking.  I found SceneKit.framework under "Link Binary With Libraries" and set the Status to "Optional".  Thanks!