# Is there any way to import a library that requires iOS >=14.0 and still support iOS 11?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, binary

I need to use a `library` for my application that requires to be added in the old-fashioned way (there is no `pod` available or anything else).
This `framework` has the requirement for `iOS 14.0` as the minimum supported version.

Is there any way to have that application compile and fully work for a lower version of `iOS`? My app has to support an `iOS` version down to **11.0**.

For the moment I have a crash when running the `iOS 13` **simulator** right after the application launches.
Basically, I want to check if the current running version is greater than 14.0 and initialize a `class` from the `framework`, but for the moment the `library` is included at the compile time.

[image]

**Later edit:**
I tried the following things after @Dávid Pásztor suggested the weak linking:

1. weak import the library (optional): **iOS 13** runs ok, but I have a crash on **iOS 15**: [image]
2. import the library with default values (required): on **iOS 15** the class from the library is initialized, but the **iOS 13** app crashes after splash screen:
   [image]

Comment: Yes, you just need to use weak linking. [Official docs for weak linking](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFrameworks/Concepts/WeakLinking.html). And relevant SO Q&A:[What does it mean to weak link a framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16922013/what-does-it-mean-to-weak-link-a-framework)

Comment: @DávidPásztor I've done this but the application is still crashing when trying to initialize the View Controller which imports the framework. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: You need to wrap all code that uses the framework in `#available iOS14` statements (or you can try to use `#if canImport` as well, but that might not work).

Comment: I am already creating an instance of the class using this framework only "if #available(iOS 14, *)". I will try to clean the project and compile it again. Hopefully, it is an Xcode problem. The weak framework seems to be imported correctly.